# Cakephp3 Standardize Multiple Mysql Tables into 1 Model Table/Entity

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

Okay, we are trying to set up a central site to view data from our multiple vendors that sell our product. These multiple vendors use different sales system (2 different ones to be exact) so each database look totally different. We sync with their database so the data sits on our local server. We have 3 vendors that use one system and 2 that use the other. What we need is a way to figure out for the results to come back to us in the same way.

Here are examples of the two systems:

```
System-1
     Customers =>[
         id, firstname, lastname, address
     ],
     Transactions =>[
         id, cost, paid, customer_id
     ]

System2
     Customers =>[
         id, NAMEFIRST, NAMELAST, AddressNumber, AddressString, AddressZip
     ],
     Transactions=>[
         id, COST, PAID, CUSTOMER_ID
     ]
```

I can't change the database at all. I want to be able to echo $this->Transaction->address no matter which database it is. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Entity property accessors: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#accessors-mutators

```
class Customer extends Entity {
    protected function _getFirstname($name) {
        if ($name === null && isset($this->NAMEFIRST)) {
           return $this->NAMEFIRST;
        }
        return $name;
    }
}
```